# Reason for disparate results with mdfind using Python subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I'm trying to write a Python wrapper for the UNIX `mdfind` utility. In simplest form, it works well; however, I cannot figure out one instance of odd behavior. Things get a bit odd when running more complex queries (two or more fields). Take the following example:

```
import subprocess
import itertools

def test1():
    cmd = "mdfind 'kMDItemFSName=pandoc&&kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'"
    shell_res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    find_res = mdfind(content_type='public.unix-executable',
                      name='pandoc')
    if shell_res == find_res:
        print('Passed!')

def mdfind(**kwargs):
    cmd = ['mdfind']
    for key, arg in kwargs.iteritems():
        if key in mdattributes().keys():
            md_name = mdattributes()[key]['id']
            query = '='.join([md_name, arg])
            cmd.append(query)
    if 'only_in' in kwargs:
        cmd.append('-onlyin')
        cmd.append(kwargs['only_in'])
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd)

def mdattributes():
    attributes_str = subprocess.check_output(['mdimport', '-A'])
    # prepare key names for the four columns
    keys = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'aliases')
    # create list of dicts, mapping ``keys`` to an item's columns
    data = [dict(itertools.izip(keys,
                                [item.replace("'", "")
                                 for item in attribute.split('\t\t')]))
            for attribute in attributes_str.splitlines()]
    # coerce list of dicts into large dict with nested dicts
    metadata = {}
    for md_dict in data:
        # clean up key
        key = md_dict['id'].replace('kMDItemFS', '')\
                           .replace('kMDItem', '')\
                           .replace('kMD', '')\
                           .replace('com_', '')
        metadata[key] = md_dict
    return metadata

test1()
```

This code will pass, as both the straight shell command and the wrapper created command will output the same result.

Now, take this example, which seems to me to be of the same kind, yet doesn't work:

```
def test2():
    cmd = """mdfind 'kMDItemKind=PDF&&kMDItemFSName="*epistem*"c'"""
    shell_res = run_shell(cmd)
    find_res = mdfind(kind='PDF',
                      name='"*epistem*"c')
```

The straight shell command will return the single PDF on my machine that has "Epistemology" in the title, while the wrapper made command will return 13 PDFs (I have 1,000+ PDFs on my machine in total). So, the wrapper script is filtering the thousands PDFs somehow, but apparently not by whether `*epistem*` is in the title.

Even more oddly, this command will return 144 results:

```
subprocess.check_output(['mdfind',
                          """kMDItemKind=PDF&&kMDItemFSName="*epistemolog*"c"""])
```

So, in short these three different subprocess calls give radically different numbers of results:

```
"""mdfind 'kMDItemKind=PDF&&kMDItemFSName="*epistem*"c'"""
['mdfind', 'kMDItemKind=PDF', u'kMDItemFSName="*epistem*"c']
['mdfind', """kMDItemKind=PDF&&kMDItemFSName="*epistemolog*"c"""]
```

So, my question: Why? Why does `subprocess.check_output()` return 1 result for the straight shell command (I mean where the command is a string and `shell=True` is set), 13 results for the 3 item list command, and 144 results for the 2 item list command? What is going on under the covers? How can I get the 3 item list to return only the one item that the straight shell command does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this has to do with subtle but important differences in the command line argument processing pipeline. This pipeline is complex and when invoking a command from within a programming language environment it is actually quite difficult to obtain *equivalent* behavior as typing the command in your favorite shell.

The bad thing is: depending on which method your target executable uses for parsing command line arguments (there unfortunately is -- as in many cases -- no definite standard) the outcome may vary depending among invocation methods. That is, your observation definitely has to do with the processing and interpretation of whitespace, NULL characters, dashes, and quotes.

Your question is "why?". So if you really want to get to the bottom of this, you need to look at the source code of Python's subprocess module and at the source code of your target commands command line argument parsing code. Also, you might want to have these reads:

- http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm
- http://gehrcke.de/2014/02/command-line-argument-binary-data/

In order to obtain *conceptually equivalent* behavior as typing in your shell, there is a non-ovious but dead-simple workaround: create a temporary shell script and invoke your shell from within Python and provide only one argument: the path to the shell script. I have used this method in this module for creating systematic command line tool tests:
https://github.com/jgehrcke/timegaps/blob/master/test/clitest.py